# How do I keep my file transfers from sucking up all my bandwidth?

Tags: networking, ftp, bandwidth, voip

How do I set up a router so that my file transfers have 2nd priority? My VOIP and GoToMeetings suffer if we are transferring large files from our internal network to a hosted server.

70 gig backup files; 
1 Gig Internal Network; 
12 Down, 1.5 Up Cable Internet; 
10 users; 
3 VOIP and 2 GoToMeetings work fine until we start a file transfer.

Thank you,
Jason

Comment: You might want to specify what type of hardware you have? If you're using a consumer level wifi router you probably do not have the ability to manage this but some enterprise level routers and firewalls do support QoS / Traffic Shaping.

Comment: Sounds like you upgrade your service if thats tha option.  You won't be able to apply QoS on `GoToMeeting` and `VOIP` because one is basically a web application and the other is already optimized.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, routers have a page called QoS (Quality of Service) which allows you to do exactly what you are asking for. The configuration page varies from router to router. In my Cisco router it is: [image: like this]. You can pick an application, or define a new one, and then assign it a varying priority. Since I do not know make and model of yours, I cannot be more specific, but most routers nowadays come with this specs.